# plotting list, clearing, then plotting a different list on same window with python

Tags: python, dynamic, matplotlib, plot

I have been at this for weeks,
I would like to plot 1 list then in the same window very quickly remove that list and plot another.

The reason is I have an EEG signal coming in in realtime, I convert every 40 samples to frequency domain then plot them in an effort to detect different cognition states.

for now I just created two lists from my head, and I would like list 1 to appear, disappear then list two to very quickly appear in its place

I have tried matplotlib animation but I haven't figured out how to use it its complicated to me.

```
from numpy import sin, linspace, pi
from pylab import plot, show, title, xlabel, ylabel, subplot
from scipy import fft, arange
import time

lst1 = [1000,1100,1000,1150,1100,1090,1300,1700,2000,1500,1200,1100,1000,1100,1100,1000,1150,1100]

lst = [1000,1060,1200,1600,2000,1400,1030,1300,1600,2000,1400,1100,1000,1400,1700,1800,1500,1100]


def plotSpectrum(y,Fs):
 """
 Plots a Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)
 """

 n = len(lst) # length of the signal
 k = arange(n)
 T = n/Fs
 frq = k/T # two sides frequency range
 frq = frq[range(n/2)] # one side frequency range

 Y = fft(lst)/n # fft computing and normalization
 Y = Y[range(n/2)]

 plot(frq,abs(Y),'r') # plotting the spectrum
 xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
 ylabel('|Y(freq)|')


Fs = 18.0;  # sampling rate
Ts = 1.0/Fs; # sampling interval
t = arange(0,1,Ts) # time vector


subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,lst)
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Amplitude')
subplot(2,1,2)
plotSpectrum(lst,Fs)
show()

#time.sleep(5) #here is where id like the second list to appear
#plotSpectrum(lst1,Fs)
#show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple animations you can use [pause](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pause).

```
from pylab import plot, show,  xlabel, ylabel, subplot, draw, pause

# Lists to plot
list1 = [1000,1100,1000,1150,1100,1090,1300,1700,2000,1500,1200,1100,1000,1100,1100,1000,1150,1100]
list2 = [1000,1060,1200,1600,2000,1400,1030,1300,1600,2000,1400,1100,1000,1400,1700,1800,1500,1100]

# Setup the axis
subplot(1,1,1)
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Amplitude')

# Plot the first line
lines = plot(list1,'r')
show() 
pause(1) # pause

# Remove the first line
oldLine = lines.pop()
oldLine.remove()

# Plot the second line
lines = plot(list2,'g')
draw()
```